# Prove that there exists a $n\times n$ nonsingular matrix $P$ such that $B=AP$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A,B,C,D$ be $n\times n$ matrices on $\mathbb{F}$ which satisfy
>   $A=BC$ and $B=AD$. Prove that there exists a $n\times n$ nonsingular
>   matrix $P$ such that $B=AP$.

Here is my attempt.

If $\det D\neq 0$, let $P=D$ and we are done.

If $\det C\neq 0$, let $P=C^{-1}$ and we are done.

Otherwise $\det D=0$ and by $B=AD$ we have $\det B=\det A\cdot \det D=0$.

By the same way we have $\det A=\det C=0$.

Now we get $\det A=\det B=\det C=\det D=0$ but I don't know how to do next.

Comment: Hint: Adjust $D$ by elements of the kernel of $A$.

Comment: Another hint: im(B) = im(A) and $\ker(D)\subset\ker (B)$, so $\dim\ker A = \dim\ker B\ge\dim\ker D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\mathbb F^n = \ker(D)\oplus W$ with some subspace $W$. As I wrote in the comments, we have $\dim\ker(D)\le\dim\ker(A)$. Let $\{u_1,\ldots,u_k\}$ be a basis of $\ker(D)$ and $\{v_1,\ldots,v_r\}$ a basis of $\ker(A)$. Now, define $Pu_j = v_j$, $j=1,\ldots,k$, and $P|W = D|W$. Then $AP = AD = B$ and $P$ is non-singular.